# C++ process is leaking memory slowly

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

One of our process written in C++ is leaking the memory very slowly. Valgrind is showing 0 bytes in all 3 sections (definitely lost, indirectly lost, & possibly lost). This issue is taking nearly about 6-7 months to consume 70% of systems memory with 8GB of RAM. I tried to reproduce the issue on test machine and was able to see memory consumption slowly after many requests.

Below is the valgrind results that I got:

```
==20868==
--20868-- REDIR: 0x4019f70 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x58059dd1 (???)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x4019d40 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x58059deb (???)
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
==20868== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--20868--     old: 0x04019f70 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x58059dd1 ???
--20868--     new: 0x04019f70 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c2ba90 strlen
--20868-- REDIR: 0x4019ef0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2cbe0 (strcmp)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x401aae0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c2fc60 (mempcpy)
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d9/73c39d1900dc61d8519c653c3bc405692de563.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.4.0
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so.2.9.0
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/87/91ddd49348603cd50b74652c5b25354d8fd06e.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libm-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/07/fb92afef1756f093371ce60c3ae85dd3a06325.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/a0/3c9a80e995ed5f43077ab754a258fa0e34c3cd.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libc-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/af/310f56618fc1ef9158973484f60942f11cc0fb.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libnghttp2.so.14.13.1
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libidn2.so.0.1.4
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libpsl.so.0.2.3
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libplds4.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libplc4.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libnspr4.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/0e/5cd5baa5ee8bf3648a5031b088f9a78c89364f.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/ab/007f5df96c66e515542598f5be1429ed63d86f.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.3
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libz.so.1.2.8
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/89/c6af118b6b4fb6a73ae1813e2c8bdd722956d1.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libuv.so.1.0.0
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/9c/4eb34a346260f2a77746f4e5ed837619137db7.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/0b/7f7487280fe68af9302a282fae37776a99bc80.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libunistring.so.0.1.2
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.50.1.2
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/librt-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2/701e2a24459d5b55df5549d585f091e7bcf07a.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/37/a58210fa50c91e09387765408a92909468d25b.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/9e/5e0bf5f22de7555bc4b9853240817147489258.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2.0.23
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/af/2bb3cd9fcda0b820c88aab5d80639ca5287921.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.50.1.2
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f5/054dc94443326819fbf3065cfdf5e4726f57ee.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libcrypt-2.17.so
--20868--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/9a/9be1d2234d3641b9cfe17bb7a40b82973a2802.debug ..
--20868--   .. build-id is valid
--20868-- Reading syms from /lib64/libfreebl3.so
--20868--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79e40 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f76bc0 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f7c110 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79620 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f795d0 (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f75040 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f76ae0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4c2b9f0 (__GI_strlen)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f785b0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4c2b450 (__GI_strrchr)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f6f800 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c28b5c (malloc)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f8f630 (libc.so.6:__GI_strstr) redirected to 0x4c2fef0 (__strstr_sse2)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f78cb0 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x4c2cc80 (memchr)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f7e850 (libc.so.6:__GI_memcpy) redirected to 0x4c2d580 (__GI_memcpy)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f8fbf0 (libc.so.6:strstr) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x602a620 (libc.so.6:__strstr_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2ff80 (__strstr_sse42)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f6fc20 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c29c56 (free)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f76a90 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x6030670 (libc.so.6:__strlen_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2ba50 (__strlen_sse42)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x56dd640 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2917c (operator new(unsigned long))
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f7e7e0 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x6036480 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_ssse3) redirected to 0x4c2cfa0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f74f80 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x6028640 (libc.so.6:__strchr_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2b640 (index)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x56db6f0 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4c2a106 (operator delete(void*))
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79040 (libc.so.6:__GI_memcmp) redirected to 0x4c2e4d0 (__GI_memcmp)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x60286f0 (libc.so.6:__strcmp_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2cb90 (__strcmp_sse42)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f70210 (libc.so.6:calloc) redirected to 0x4c2a8df (calloc)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f800d0 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x4c2f780 (strchrnul)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f797f0 (libc.so.6:__GI_mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c2f990 (__GI_mempcpy)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f74d80 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f88a90 (libc.so.6:__strcat_ssse3) redirected to 0x4c2b680 (strcat)
--20868-- REDIR: 0xffffffffff600400 (???:???) redirected to 0x58059dbd (???)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79680 (libc.so.6:__GI_memset) redirected to 0x4c2ee80 (memset)
--20868-- REDIR: 0xffffffffff600000 (???:???) redirected to 0x58059db3 (???)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79000 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x4a24780 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x6053910 (libc.so.6:__memcmp_sse4_1) redirected to 0x4c2e610 (__memcmp_sse4_1)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79440 (libc.so.6:__GI_memmove) redirected to 0x4c2f1d0 (__GI_memmove)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f7fec0 (libc.so.6:__GI___rawmemchr) redirected to 0x4c2f7e0 (__GI___rawmemchr)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x56dd700 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c29821 (operator new[](unsigned long))
--20868-- REDIR: 0x603b820 (libc.so.6:__memmove_ssse3) redirected to 0x4c2cd40 (memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f76ce0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strncmp) redirected to 0x4c2c220 (__GI_strncmp)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x5f79ce0 (libc.so.6:__GI_stpcpy) redirected to 0x4c2e8d0 (__GI_stpcpy)
--20868-- REDIR: 0x56db720 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4c2a5b6 (operator delete[](void*))
==20868== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==20868==    at 0x4E4281D: ??? (syscall-template.S:81)
==20868==    by 0x49969C: RTSPServer::~RTSPServer() (RTSPServer.cpp:394)
==20868==    by 0x4A9DB3: RTSPServerWithREGISTERProxying::~RTSPServerWithREGISTERProxying() (RTSPServer.cpp:2816)
==20868==    by 0x45D2F5: iv::Server::~Server() (Server.cpp:292)
==20868==    by 0x45D329: iv::Server::~Server() (Server.cpp:311)
==20868==    by 0x4804D9: MediaLookupTable::remove(char const*) (Media.cpp:151)
==20868==    by 0x480100: Medium::close(UsageEnvironment&, char const*) (Media.cpp:53)
==20868==    by 0x48013F: Medium::close(Medium*) (Media.cpp:59)
==20868==    by 0x45CE03: iv::Server::releaseServer(iv::Server*&) (Server.cpp:269)
==20868==    by 0x45A5B8: main (Main.cpp:543)
==20868==
==20868== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 5 open at exit.
==20868== Open file descriptor 2: /var/log/ivrtspproxyserver/log/ivrtspproxyserver.log
==20868==    at 0x5FDA3A7: dup2 (syscall-template.S:81)
==20868==    by 0x476FBD: Logger::startNewSession(char) (Logger.cpp:712)
==20868==    by 0x4751CC: Logger::createLogFile(std::string, std::string, char) (Logger.cpp:441)
==20868==    by 0x4570FD: LogFile() (Main.cpp:84)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== Open file descriptor 1: /var/log/ivrtspproxyserver/log/ivrtspproxyserver.log
==20868==    at 0x5FDA3A7: dup2 (syscall-template.S:81)
==20868==    by 0x476FA7: Logger::startNewSession(char) (Logger.cpp:711)
==20868==    by 0x4751CC: Logger::createLogFile(std::string, std::string, char) (Logger.cpp:441)
==20868==    by 0x4570FD: LogFile() (Main.cpp:84)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== Open file descriptor 4: /var/log/ivrtspproxyserver/log/ivrtspproxyserver.log
==20868==    at 0x4E42F40: __open_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==20868==    by 0x476E4B: Logger::startNewSession(char) (Logger.cpp:696)
==20868==    by 0x4751CC: Logger::createLogFile(std::string, std::string, char) (Logger.cpp:441)
==20868==    by 0x4570FD: LogFile() (Main.cpp:84)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== Open file descriptor 3: /home/ec2-user/akshay/mem_leak/IV-proxyserver/ProxyServer/leak_details.txt
==20868==    <inherited from parent>
==20868==
==20868== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/2
==20868==    <inherited from parent>
==20868==
==20868==
==20868== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20868==     in use at exit: 261 bytes in 4 blocks
==20868==   total heap usage: 838 allocs, 834 frees, 289,041 bytes allocated
==20868==
==20868== Searching for pointers to 4 not-freed blocks
==20868== Checked 1,354,824 bytes
==20868==
==20868== 46 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==20868==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==20868==    by 0x571E858: allocate (new_allocator.h:111)
==20868==    by 0x571E858: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:1057)
==20868==    by 0x57202E4: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (basic_string.tcc:578)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: _S_construct_aux<char const*> (basic_string.h:5031)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: _S_construct<char const*> (basic_string.h:5052)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:665)
==20868==    by 0x4570BB: LogFile() (Main.cpp:84)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== 55 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==20868==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==20868==    by 0x571E858: allocate (new_allocator.h:111)
==20868==    by 0x571E858: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:1057)
==20868==    by 0x57202E4: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (basic_string.tcc:578)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: _S_construct_aux<char const*> (basic_string.h:5031)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: _S_construct<char const*> (basic_string.h:5052)
==20868==    by 0x572070B: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:665)
==20868==    by 0x4570E1: LogFile() (Main.cpp:84)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==20868==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==20868==    by 0x4782AC: IVUtils::Object<IVUtils::Mutex>::CreateNew() (Object.h:21)
==20868==    by 0x4781DF: IVUtils::CreateMutex() (Mutex.cpp:73)
==20868==    by 0x474CCE: Logger::Logger() (Logger.cpp:404)
==20868==    by 0x456FEF: LogFile() (Main.cpp:74)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==20868==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==20868==    by 0x456FE4: LogFile() (Main.cpp:74)
==20868==    by 0x458164: main (Main.cpp:283)
==20868==
==20868== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20868==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20868==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20868==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20868==    still reachable: 261 bytes in 4 blocks
==20868==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==20868==                         stdstring          : 101 bytes in 2 blocks
==20868==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20868==
==20868== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==20868== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What more can be the reason for such slow memory consumption?

Comment: Maybe it's not so much a memory leak as a data structure that grows gradually. Valgrind wouldn't necessarily show this as a leak.

Comment: According to your valgrind output, your program is *not* leaking any memory.  Therefore, if the program's RAM usage is growing over time, it must be that its data structures are getting larger.  Previously when I've seen this behavior, it turned out to be e.g. a `std::vector` that the code kept appending items to indefinitely, but never cleared or removed any items from.  (of course any variable-size data structure could have the same problem; I'm only using `std::vector` as a simple example)

Comment: So you think the problem is in `LogFile`? Would help to see that code.

Comment: would gdb help me to identify which data structure is growing gradually or which one is getting filled and is not cleared once use of that entry is done?

Comment: gdb is not as helpful as you'd like. You'd have to stop the program periodically and inspect all of the objects that COULD be growing and either justify or further inspect those that had grown since the last time you inspected. If you can accelerate the program to force a quicker consumption of resources this may be reasonable. If not you could find yourself running a debug instance for months before you spot and confirm the villain. Periodic logging of the size of the objects of interest may be more practical.

Comment: Hmm please remove the C++ tag, this has nothing to do with C++ !!!

Comment: @Yunfei Chen future readers may use the C++ tag to search for similar issues.

Comment: @PaulFloyd do you see any C++ code in there at all?? Cause I sure dont.....

Comment: The callstacks are clearly from C++.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your traces, you have 4 things still in use - logger, mutex for logger and two std::strings.

I suggest that you instrument your code with client requests (see [here](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs)). That way you can see where memory is getting used incrementally. I particular, try using the `VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK` macro.

On average, you are adding something like 300-350 bytes per second. Use your knowledge of the times for the logging events when running under Valgrind - you want it to run long enough to capture a few events at least.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at such bugs, where you believe that the likely cause is container growth, is to use https://github.com/vmware/chap

You don't need to instrument your process at all.  Just use gcore to gather a live core of your process.  Possibly do this more than once, say an hour apart.

For each core, open it in chap then try:

```
redirect on
summarize used
```

or

```
redirect on
summarize used /sortby bytes
```

Comparing the results will give you a sense of what sort of allocations are accumulating and you can look further at those.  Let's say, for example, that you discover that you are seeing an increase in allocations of type Foo.  You can then do

```
enumerate used Foo
```

to get a list of all the addresses of such allocations, then pick one such address and use something like the following repeatedly to figure out why they are held in memory:

```
describe incoming <address>
```

In that case the initial address you might use is one from the enumeration.